# Puppetter memory leak after page open for long

Tags: puppeteer

My script open 60 headless chrome browsers with proxy, one page each with and write on a text on my website for testing when they receive command by firebase. It works fine but after 2 hours they start to be slowing and then they cant execute the commands sent anymore. I`m using theses flags in my chorme:

```
'--proxy-server=downstream-proxy-address',
                  '--proxy-server='+myip,
                  '--no-sandbox',
                  '--unlimited-storage', 
                  '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                  '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
                  '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
                  '--disable-gpu',
                  '--window-size=1920x1080',
```

I tried to close each browser after 10 minutes and reopen again, but it doesnt work. What is the best solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Kindly do share more information :) Are you using a queue to create the browsers? What kind of website does it open? What kind of commands they get from firebase? What kind of commands they get after two hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across with the same issue. Later identified its due to the browser which is not closed in the script. If you are catching the exception add the await browser.close() in finally block as below

```
try{
   var browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      devtools: false,
      args: [
        '--no-sandbox','--disable-setuid-sandbox','--ignore-certificate-errors'],
      ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation','--no-first-run'],
      executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
     });
   var page = await browser.newPage();
   await page.goto(url, {timeout: 20000});
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    response.status(500).send('ERROR: ' + err)
  } finally{
    await browser.close()
  }
```